# Non-late answer appearing on Late Answer review queue

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

[I just audited a question from the Late Answers queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15744826), and something was off.

According to the audit, the question was asked 11 days ago, and the answer was posted 11 days ago. In fact, the answer lists *answered Mar 24 at 19:58*, while the question lists *asked Mar 24 at 18:55*.

That answer is not late. It was posted *within an hour* of the original question. I'm mainly suspecting this is a bug regarding late posts.

Comment: This is not SO specific in any way. This also involve a potential bug in the treatment of late answer.

Comment: @Gnemlock, I have edited the question to focus on the non-late part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an *audit*. The only things about audits that are not faked in Late Answers and First Posts are a) the place they were posted (as a question, or as an answer to a particular question); b) the text displayed in the body of the post; c) the link to the real post outside /review; and, it appears, d) the actual dates. (The fact that that was actually listed accurately is a bit surprising to me.)

Everything else — comments, author's username, rep, accepted or not, score, validity for inclusion in the queue in the first place? All lies.

This is because it's an *audit*, and it doesn't need to be real, it just needs to be plausible to test your responses where they won't make any difference to a real post.

(Suggested Edits makes up edits out of wholecloth, and the only things real are the original post before the edits and the edit summary, randomly drawn from the pool. Low Quality Posts will include question audits, whether or not questions are funneled into the queue in the first place. Close Votes and Reopen Votes will pull in questions that never got a close vote in the first place. And so on and so forth.)

Comment: Different queue has their own guideline for reviewing - in this case, this is acceptable as an answer to me. Throwing things from one queue to somewhere else is not a good idea; they are likely to cause disputed audits.